# How to validate if a scanner collects the correct character, otherwise run process again in JAVA?

Tags: java, char, java.util.scanner

I have a Java program where I want to ask a user whether to create a Savings Bank Account or a Current Bank Account.

The Question: "Would you like to create a Savings Account (Y/N)?"

```java
// Collect Character to validate a savings or current account:
char yes_no = 'a'; //Why can't declare empty char?

System.out.println(ANSI_PURPLE + "Do you want to create a Savings Account (Y/N)?");
System.out.print(ANSI_RESET + " Choose an option > ");

//Check if input is valid. Otherwise allow user to select again:
while(!sc.hasNext()) {
   System.out.println(ANSI_RED + " ERROR: Invalid option! ");
   System.out.print(ANSI_RESET + " Choose an option > ");
   yes_no = sc.next().charAt(0);
}

if (yes_no == 'Y' || yes_no == 'y') {
    System.out.println("Y");
} else if(yes_no == 'N' || yes_no == 'n') {
    System.out.println("N");
} else {
    //run again to collect valid input
}
```

---

With Integers I can do something like this:

```java
// Check if input is valid. Otherwise allow user to select again:
while(!sc.hasNextInt()) {
    System.out.println(ANSI_RED + " ERROR: Invalid option! ");
    System.out.print(ANSI_RESET + " Choose an option > ");
    sc.next();
}
        
// Store input on variable and process request:
menuInput = sc.nextInt();
menuManager(menuInput);
```

Why can't I do something similar with characters?

---

CORRECT ANSWER TO MY QUESTION:

```java
// Collect Character to validate a savings or current account:
char yes_no = 'a';
System.out.println(ANSI_PURPLE + "Do you want to create a Savings Account (Y/N)?");
System.out.print(ANSI_RESET + " Choose an option > ");
yes_no = sc.next().charAt(0);

// Check if input is valid. Otherwise allow user to select again:
while (!(yes_no == 'Y' || yes_no == 'y' || yes_no == 'N' || yes_no == 'n')) {
    System.out.println(ANSI_RED + " ERROR: Invalid option! ");
    System.out.print(ANSI_RESET + " Choose an option > ");
    yes_no = sc.next().charAt(0);
}
System.out.println("input was " + yes_no);
```

Comment: Shouldn't the if and else statements in the first code should also be in the while loop?

Comment: It doesn't make any difference, I can still put "example" "L", "0rqw124" in and doesn't run again or give me an error. program stops

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Why can't declare empty `char` [Answer for your question](https://www.coderanch.com/t/392740/java/Set-char-empty)
2. Do small change in your code to work fine with `char` literal

Use before while loop.

```
System.out.println(ANSI_PURPLE + "Do you want to create a Savings Account (Y/N)?");
System.out.print(ANSI_RESET + " Choose an option > ");
yes_no = sc.next().charAt(0);
```

Then check for condition with your expected input, like:

```
while (!(yes_no == 'Y' || yes_no == 'y' || yes_no == 'N' || yes_no == 'n')) {
    System.out.println(ANSI_RED + " ERROR: Invalid option! ");
    System.out.print(ANSI_RESET + " Choose an option > ");
    yes_no = sc.next().charAt(0);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do this using do while loop

```
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
        String answer = "";
        char ch;
        do{
            System.out.println("Enter Value");
            answer = scanner.nextLine();
            ch = answer.charAt(0);
            if(ch=='Y' || ch=='y' || ch=='N' || ch=='n'){
                break;
            }
        }while(true);
        System.out.println(ch);
```

Comment: Add some explanation to why it will not work with `hasNext()` if you can.

Comment: Rather separate if make use of `while` and put condition there only like: `while(!(ch=='Y' || ch=='y' || ch=='N' || ch=='n'))`.

Comment: Too complicated! Why use a string and confuse everything. Also this gives an error. answer from @ajayg2808 much simpler, and straight to the point!